# How do I access model properties in a view in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a model that has a property `FreeAccess`. I pass this model to a view, so at the top of the view I have the statement `@model XXX.Models.ModelName`

I want to be able to do the following:

```
@if(model.FreeAccess == true)
{
    // Do something here
}
```

but it's not working. I've tried `if (model => model.FreeAccess == true)` but that comes back with `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool'`.

So where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you passed your `Model` when returning your view from `Controller`? `return View(yourModel);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the page inherit from the correct type? 
If so I think its:

```
@if(Model.FreeAccess == true)
{
// Do something here
}
```

(notice casing)

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thank you!